Regarding Column Alias Name set to Arabic in select statement
I want to display column alias names in Arabic text in select statements. For instance, you can view this query:
SELECT nID, GOLD_OWNSA AS "OWNSA",
    convert(char(10), GOLDPRICE_DATE, 103), GOLDPRICE_TIME 
    , convert(char(10), UpdatedOn, 103), UpdatedBy, CreatedBy
    , btSTATUS
FROM GOLD_PRICE_MASTER 
WHERE 1=1

When I execute the above query, I want the column alias name displayed in Arabic text rather than English. As you can see above query as "OWNSA". Inside this I have to set an alias name with Arabic text.
I tired using N'يبيبيبيب'  in place of as OWNSA but it returns ?????????.
How can I get Arabic column aliases?

You're making it harder than it needs to be. You can just use the text you want:
SELECT    nID, GOLD_OWNSA  as يبيبيبيب,
     convert(char(10),GOLDPRICE_DATE,103 ) ,GOLDPRICE_TIME 
    ,convert(char(10),UpdatedOn,103 ) ,UpdatedBy ,CreatedBy ,  
    btSTATUS
FROM        GOLD_PRICE_MASTER 
WHERE 1=1

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/RvYZwJTI

